# Checkbox holder using setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-checkbox

I'm trying to make a listview with checkboxes, I have tried a code and it worked correctly but I faced a problem when trying to handle the checkbox states. The problem appears in this line of code

`holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((MyActivity) context);`

because the code I have tried is using Adapter.java file separated from the MainActivity.java file, but in my code all are in one file so I don't know how to use this line in my code, I have tried this

`holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((this) context);`

but also a wrong statement

The reason of using this line of holder is that when I checked a checkbox and scroll down through the others items, the checked checkbox is automatically unchecked, Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Here is my Adapter Code

```
@Override public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder=null;
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.check1 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check1);
            holder.check2 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check2);
            itemView.setTag(holder);
       }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
        }
        holder.check1.setTag(position);
        final Item item = items.get(position);
        holder.textView1.setText(item.getName());
        holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                                                         if(buttonView.isPressed()){

                                                         if (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                                                             Item p = items.get(position);
                                                             p.setSelected(isChecked);
                                                         }

                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                 }
        );
holder.check2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                                                         if(buttonView.isPressed()){
                                                                               if (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                                                                 Item p = items.get(position);
                                                                 p.setSelected(isChecked);
                                                             }

                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                 }
        );
        holder.check1.setChecked(item.isSelected());
        holder.check2.setChecked(item.isSelected());
        return itemView;
    }
}private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView1;
   public CheckBox  check2,check1;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make your activity implement `OnCheckedChangedListener` interface, which forces to implement the following method :

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
```

Now pass the reference of your activity to the your adapter as an argument of type OnCheckedChangeListener and name it listener :

```
MyAdapter myadapter = new MyAdapter(context, MyActivity.this,listdata);
```

Then, in your adapter class, set the listener for your checkbox like :

```
holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {


            if(buttonView.isPressed()){
            //Write the logic to determine if the checkbox must be checked or not                
                }
          }
      }
    );
```

**The point here is** using the **isPressed()** method of the checkbox.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work
`if(buttonView.isPressed()){
                                                             int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                                                             if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                                                                 Item p = items.get(pos);
                                                                 p.setSelected(isChecked);
                                                             }

                                                             }`

Comment: avoid pasting code in comments. Add the adapter implementation to your question

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I have added my adapter implementation

Comment: Have you tried using "position" instead of lv.getPosition() ?

Comment: yes, try to use the position that is given to the getView() method.

Comment: The Application, unfortunately has been stopped when I tried to check one of the checkboxes

Comment: You're welcom. Glad I could help.

Comment: I'm sorry there is another problem appears, I have two checkboxes, when I check one of them the other one is automatically checked, and also when I unchecked one of them the other one is automatically unchecked

I have repeated "holder.chkbox.." for the both checkboxes

Comment: I have updated my Adapter Implementation in my question

Comment: add another condition in the if(isPressed) :  buttonView.getId == R.id.mycheckbox,

Comment: getId is colored in red, Does it has any specific declaration or something ?
`if(buttonView.isPressed()){buttonView.getId == R.id.check1;`

Comment: Just want to add, I think it's actually better to use isChecked, not buttonView.isPressed(). Sorry, I thought my answer included if(isChecked) but I didn't. The reason it's passed to the callback is so you can use it and avoid the extra call to isPressed(). @Farhad is there a reason you made a point of using isPressed() other than it was a way of knowing the item was checked? I'd suggest updating this answer to use isChecked otherwise :)

Comment: I have tried if(isChecked). But the problem is still the same, as I checked one of the checkboxes the other checkbox is automatically checked

Comment: any help here please! The problem is when I checked one of the check boxes, the other checkbox is automatically checked, I think because they have the same position

Comment: I will definitely help. But it is recommended to open another question and paste the adapter code so that also other users can help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the example code you worked with, your activity implemented OnCheckedChangeListener, so you needed to pass the context. In your Adapter you can do it as follows:

```
holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           // logic
       }
   }
);
```

In the code where you had it working, you probably had an overridden onCheckedChanged method in your activity. Move the logic of that where I have // logic above.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work
`if(buttonView.isPressed()){
                                                             int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                                                             if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                                                                 Item p = items.get(pos);
                                                                 p.setSelected(isChecked);
                                                             }

                                                             }`

Comment: You'll need to debug what the problem is. "It doesn't work" isn't enough for us to tell what's wrong. You're moving code that we can't see. This is something further to your initial issue. If you're seeing errors , Android Studio should be leaving a red line and explanation of what's wrong.

Comment: The problem is that the application is stopped working when i'm trying to check one of the checkbox, I have added the Adapter Implementation to my question

Comment: The Code worked fine, thank you
But another problem has been appeared, I have two checkboxes, when I check one of them the other one is automatically checked, and also when I unchecked one of them the other one is automatically unchecked I have repeated "holder.chkbox.." for the both checkboxes

I updated my Adapter Code in the question